# SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-84.84

Tags: encryption, ssl, java

I'm facing a weird issue on our server that happens intermittently not quite often (once a month) and can't figure it out.

I've searched for this and found [this thread](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/164608/what-is-causing-javaxnetsslsslexception-unsupporte.html) which is pretty similar to my issue. However, previous question is about `Unknown-0.0` whilst my error shows `Unknown-84.84`. Also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196436/ssl-handshaking-with-older-clients-using-sslengine-jsse) although I cannot find what `84.84` means. Checking at this [OpenJdk class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/ssl/ProtocolVersion.java) I can come up with `84.84` is `major.minor` versions but couldn't find what `84` version stands for (btw, I use Oracle jdk so I'm not sure if it's the same code).

We are using `TLSv1` on our client through this connection factory:

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                                            sslcontext,
                                            new String[] { "TLSv1" },
                                            null,
                                            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER
                                        );
```

I was wondering if someone knows what is my error about or give me any insight about this.

The java stack trace if the following:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-84.84
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:524)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:509)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:152)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:270)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
```

Comment: I would not be horribly surprised if `Unknown-84.84` referred to the first two bytes of the TCP datagram - the first two bytes indicate the [version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_record) in use, where SSLv3 is 0x0300, TLSv1 is 0x0301, etc. etc.  When something that's *not* TLS gets shoved down that pipe, well, it takes those first two bytes and says "Hey!  This isn't a TLS version I know!  It's 0x8484" or "It's 0x5454!".  If possible, I suggest getting a packet capture and seeing what's really going on (the handshake is unencrypted and can be explored).

Comment: @gwowenfahr the version is **second and third** bytes (for TLS and SSLv3 format) and is in **decimal** so 84.84 is 0x54 0x54. Which in ASCII is "TT", FWTW. I concur a capture should help, matched up with the times of the errors if they are rare compared to good connections as it sounds like.